# Get min and max row from table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

From a table with the columns: `id(pk), type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id, lines(int4), created_at(date)`

How can I select the row with `min(lines)` and `max(lines)` for (type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id) and also the value of `created_at` when min(lines) and the same for max value.

Dummy data:

```
type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id, lines, created_at
1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 2015-04-01
1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2015-03-01
1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 2015-03-02
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2015-04-01
1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2015-03-01
1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 2015-03-04
```

Expected output:

```
type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id, min, min_created_at, max, max_created_at
1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2015-03-01, 11, 2015-03-02
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2015-04-01, 6, 2015-03-04
```

Comment: Where do  the `11` and `2015-03-02` in the result come from? 12 is bigger than 11.

Comment: How should ties be handled?

Comment: @Lennart If its a tie, min and max will have the same value.

Comment: @alex the question is, if there are ties, the `created_at` column may have different values. Which should be shown then?

Comment: @ypercube where created_at has the smallest value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is using window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id,
    first_value(lines)      OVER wmin AS min_lines, 
    first_value(created_at) OVER wmin AS min_created_at, 
    first_value(lines)      OVER wmax AS max_lines,
    first_value(created_at) OVER wmax AS max_created_at
FROM 
    tableX
WINDOW 
    wmin AS (PARTITION BY type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id 
             ORDER BY lines ASC, created_at ASC), 
    wmax AS (PARTITION BY type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id 
             ORDER BY lines DESC, created_at ASC) ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d95fd/4).

Comment: The WINDOW construction is neat, haven't seen that one before, thanks

Comment: In that case, you may want only one window and use both `first_value` and `last_value`

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right, what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM whatever ORDER BY type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id LIMIT 1) AS x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM whatever ORDER BY type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS x;
```

It returns the row with the most whatever and the row with the least whatever

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** This is not exactly what OP would want (See the accepted answer for that), but may come in handy for people landing on this question.

I stumbled across an tiny optimisation I needed to do and couldn't use `WINDOW` functions because I was using a `GROUP BY` clause and would need multiple windows.

I ended up using this hack:

```sql
WITH
  vars AS (
    SELECT '=D=' AS delimiter
      , 0 AS column_created_at
      , 1 AS column_lines
      , 2 AS column_other_field
  ),
  grouping_query AS (
    SELECT
      type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id,
      created_at -- 0, order column
        || delimiter || lines -- 1
        || delimiter || other_field -- 2
        AS info_by_created_at
    FROM
      tableX, vars
  )
SELECT
  type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id,
  split_part(MIN(info_by_created_at), delimiter, column_lines) AS min_lines_by_created_at
FROM
  grouping_query, vars
GROUP BY
  type_id, book_id, title_id, page_id
```